# Which regeneration was the longest according to the Doctors timeline

Tags: doctor-who

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How old were each of the Doctor's incarnations?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/how-old-were-each-of-the-doctors-incarnations)

It is obvious that time passes for the Doctor that we do not see. When the 10th doctor regenerates he is identified as 906, and in a Town called Mercy, he says he is 1200. That means nearly 300 years has past for the doctor since his 11th regeneration.

So which regeneration lasted the longest for the Doctor?

Comment: Well I'll be darned, thanks for the link!

Comment: Based on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/how-old-were-each-of-the-doctors-incarnations the current Doctor wins with 300.