# Why didn't the Doctor remember encountering the clockwork droids before in his 10th incarnation?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Deep Breath* after seeing droids, he tried to remember seeing these things before but doesn't put it right:

> DOCTOR: I've seen this before. I'm missing something.
>   CLARA: Doctor.
>   DOCTOR: It's the brand new head, rebooting.
>   CLARA: Come on.
>   DOCTOR: I've seen this before.

and also

> DOCTOR: SS Marie Antoinette. Out of control repair droids cannibalising human beings. I know that this is familiar, but I just can't seem to place it
>   DOCTOR: Sister ship of the Madame De Pompadour. No, not getting it.

Why didn't the Doctor remember encountering the clockwork droids before in his 10th incarnation? Did his memories of all his 13 faces' adventures need to recharge?

Comment: That's quite literally the point of the entire episode

Comment: how thats why i made this question i dint get this question

Comment: Did he ever know that the ship was called the *SS Madame de Pompadour*? To him, it was just some unknown ship manned by clockwork robots that for some unknown-to-him reason had time-portals to the life of the *actual* Madame de Pompadour. The name of the ship itself was only revealed to viewers at the end of the episode.

Comment: From your own quoted script, "DOCTOR: It's the brand new head, rebooting." Doesn't this answer the question for you?

Answer (score 6):

There are two reasons.

### Post-Regenerative Trauma

The Doctor is [consistently](http://metro.co.uk/2013/07/29/doctor-who-7-memorable-post-regeneration-moments-3900230/) quite hazy after a regeneration; this confusion is typically chalked up to something called "post-regenerative trauma," and his memory is often affected.

For instance, the Eighth Doctor forgot his entire identity, including his species:

> **Doctor:** I don't know who I am, but I know you know me.
>
> **Grace** Please go away.
>
> **Doctor:** Please, you're my only hope.
>
> **Grace** I'll call security!
>
> **Doctor:** Do you know who I am?
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* (1996)</sup>

This is also why he's rather manic in *Deep Breath*, a far cry from the more reserved character of later episodes. Basically, he hasn't quite finished settling in yet.

### It was a long time ago

The Doctor doesn't have a perfect memory; he forgets old adventures, just as you or I forget things that happened long ago. The Eleventh Doctor expresses a similar confusion regarding the Great Intelligence, faintly recognizing the name but not recalling their [previous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Abominable_Snowmen) [confrontations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Web_of_Fear):

> **Doctor:** The Great Intelligence. Rings a bell. The Great Intelligence.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* 2012 Christmas Special "The Snowmen"</sup>

From the Doctor's perspective, it's been [a](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/how-old-were-each-of-the-doctors-incarnations) long [time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46872/how-old-is-the-doctor-at-the-end-of-the-time-of-the-doctor) since the SS Madame de Pompadour; it's not unreasonable for his memory of the event to have faded.

Comment: so when does the memories of all his 13 faces adventures come back after renenerating

Comment: @user62983 He typically settles in by the end of his first post-regeneration episode, and can recall most things by that point. However, as I point out, he may still be fuzzy on things that took place a long time ago

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Peter Capaldi on the Doctor Who fan club YouTube, when he first regenerated he was all over the place. He had spent around 1100 years on Trenzalore, if you go by Matt Smith being 904 and at the end of *Deep Breath* saying 2000; he was also granted a new regeneration cycle, which has never been done, and compared to other regenerations it was a massive one. If you put those 2 together along with the standard fuzziness the Doctor gets from regenerating, it was most probably the whole thing in one.

So along with getting nurse and Clara getting mixed up, assuming it was a 2nd dinosaur, realising the regeneration has gave him a face of a previous human he rescued (remember *The Fires of Pompeii*), then previous adventures are obviously the bottom of the pile of things he needs to remember.

Comment: this So along with getting nurse and Clara getting mixed up, assuming it was a 2nd dinosaur, realising the regeneration has gave him a face of a previous human he rescued (remember The Fires of Pompeii), then previous adventures are obviously the bottom of the pile of things he needs to remember. i dont get

Comment: they are all the things in the episode deep breath that doctor forgets or does not realise, so its only right he forgets about the clockwork ship

Comment: why? he should remember everything in all of his past 13 faces adventures